# How do I copy an object in Java?

Tags: java, object, copy, clone

Consider the code below:

```
DummyBean dum = new DummyBean();
dum.setDummy("foo");
System.out.println(dum.getDummy()); // prints 'foo'

DummyBean dumtwo = dum;
System.out.println(dumtwo.getDummy()); // prints 'foo'

dum.setDummy("bar");
System.out.println(dumtwo.getDummy()); // prints 'bar' but it should print 'foo'
```

So, I want to copy the `dum` to `dumtwo` and change `dum` without affecting the `dumtwo`. But the code above is not doing that. When I change something in `dum`, the same change is happening in `dumtwo` also.

I guess, when I say `dumtwo = dum`, Java copies the **reference only**. So, is there any way to create a fresh copy of `dum` and assign it to `dumtwo`?

Answer (score 704, accepted):

Create a copy constructor:

```
class DummyBean {
  private String dummy;

  public DummyBean(DummyBean another) {
    this.dummy = another.dummy; // you can access  
  }
}
```

Every object has also a clone method which can be used to copy the object, but don't use it. It's way too easy to create a class and do improper clone method. If you are going to do that, read at least what Joshua Bloch has to say about it in *[Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective+java+clone&source=bl&ots=yXGhLnv4O4&sig=zvEip5tp5KGgwqO1sCWgtGyJ1Ns&hl=en&ei=CYANSqygK8jktgfM-JGcCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA54,M1)*.

Comment: But then he'd have to change his code to DummyBean two = new DummyBean(one);  Right?

Comment: Does this method effectively accomplish the same thing as a deep copy?

Comment: @MatthewPiziak, to me - this would not be a deep clone since any nested objects would still be referencing the original source instance, not a duplicate unless each reference (non-value type) object supplies the same constructor template as above.

Comment: Can someone confirm if this really works? It looks like it will create another DummyBeam instance, but both dummy's will still refer to the same String...

Comment: @Timmmm: Yes, they will reference the same String but because it is immutable, it is ok. Same goes for primitives. For non-primitives, you would just do copy contructor call recursively. e.g. If DummyBean referenced FooBar then FooBar should have contructor FooBar(FooBar another), and dummy should call this.foobar = new FooBar(another.foobar)

Comment: If you do: DummyBean two = new DummyBean(one); one.setDummy("johndoe"); then two.getDummy() will be "johndoe", so this is not a correct answer.

Comment: @ChristianVielma: No, it won't be "johndoe". Like Timmmm said, the string itself is immutable. With one, setDummy(..) you set the reference in one to point to "johndoe", but not the one in one.

Comment: This solution does not work on abstract base classes, which makes it pretty useless in many OOP design patterns.

Comment: With all Eclipse code generation features, I am surprised there isn't one to create the constructor. I sometimes have configuration classes with a lot of fields and it sure would help if Eclipse could generate that copy constructor automatically.

Comment: This is a very limited solution, because it only works when there are no subclasses. That is, if you know at compile time what class the object has.

Comment: I really don't like the `copy constructor` since this is not clear that a constructor would copy an instance instead of simply take some values or using his reference. I prefer to use a clone method that is more comprehensive. With `DummyBean DummyBean.clone()`, you can tell easily the output but the constructor is vague.

Comment: It could be good to narrow the description as "Every object has also a protected clone method which can be used to copy the object by implementing Cloneable interface".

Comment: if you have 100 fields, this is hard to do.

Comment: How to copy all properties of a class at once rather than doing the assignment one by one. Because you see i have a class with around 50 properties, and there is a high chance that i might miss assignment of some of them. Any way out ?

Comment: What about classes that have already been defined and can't be changed?

Comment: How to create it automatically?

Answer (score 457):

**Basic:** Object Copying in Java.

Let us Assume an object- `obj1`, that contains two objects, **containedObj1** and **containedObj2**. 
[image]

**shallow copying:**
shallow copying creates a new `instance` of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it. **Object class** provides a `clone` method and provides support for the shallow copying.
 
[image]

**Deep copying:**
A deep copy occurs when *an object is copied along with the objects to which it refers*. Below image shows `obj1` after a deep copy has been performed on it. *Not only has `obj1` been copied*, but the objects contained within it have been copied as well. We can use `Java Object Serialization` to make a deep copy. Unfortunately, this approach has some problems too([detailed examples](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)). 
[image]

**Possible Problems:**
`clone` is tricky to implement correctly.
It's better to use [Defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15), [copy constructors](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12)(as @egaga reply) or [static factory methods](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21).

1. If you have an object, that you know has a public `clone()` method, but you don’t know the type of the object at compile time, then you have problem. Java has an interface called `Cloneable`. In practice, we should implement this interface if we want to make an object `Cloneable`. `Object.clone` is **protected**, so we must *override* it with a public method in order for it to be accessible.
2. Another problem arises when we try **deep copying** of a *complex object*. Assume that the `clone()` method of all member object variables also does deep copy, this is too risky of an assumption. You must control the code in all classes.

For example [org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone%28java.io.Serializable%29) will have method for Deep clone using serialization([Source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4-sources.jar!/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.java?format=ok)). If we need to clone Bean then there are couple of utility methods in [org.apache.commons.beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) ([Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.java)).

- `cloneBean` will Clone a bean based on the available property getters and setters, even if the bean class itself does not implement Cloneable.
- `copyProperties` will Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for all cases where the property names are the same.

Comment: Can you please explain what is object contained within another?

Comment: @Chandra Sekhar "shallow copying creates a new instance of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it" that's wrong to mention all the fields,bcz objects don't get copied only the references get copied which points to the same object that old one(original) was pointing to.

Comment: @sunny - Chandra's description is correct. And so is your description of what happens; I am saying that you have an incorrect understanding of the meaning of "copies all the fields". The field **is** the reference, it is not the object being referred to. "copying all fields" **means** "copying all those references". It is good that you pointed out what exactly this means, for anyone else who has the same mis-interpretation as you, of the statement "copying all fields". :)

Comment: ... if we think in terms of some lower-level OO language, with "pointers" to objects, such a field would contain the address in memory (such as "0x70FF1234") at which the object data is found. That address is the "field value" that is being copied (assigned). You are correct that the end result is that both objects have fields that refer to (point at) the same object.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy

Answer (score 166):

In the package `import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;` there is a method:

```
SerializationUtils.clone(Object);
```

Example:

```
this.myObjectCloned = SerializationUtils.clone(this.object);
```

Comment: As long as the object implements `Serializable`

Comment: In this case cloned object has no reference to the original, if the last one is static.

Comment: A third party library just to clone object!

Comment: @Khan, "a third party library just to" is an entirely separate discussion! :D

Comment: I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` on Android 4, 5 and 6:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
org.apache.commons.lang3.-$$Lambda$Validate$0cAgQbsjQIo0VHKh79UWkAcDRWk`

Comment: This works only if all the objects inside this Object are serialisable.

Answer (score 113):

Just follow as below:

```
public class Deletable implements Cloneable{

    private String str;
    public Deletable(){
    }
    public void setStr(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("The String is "+str);
    }
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

and wherever you want to get another object, simple perform cloning.
e.g:

```
Deletable del = new Deletable();
Deletable delTemp = (Deletable ) del.clone(); // this line will return you an independent
                                 // object, the changes made to this object will
                                 // not be reflected to other object
```

Comment: Did you test this? I could use this for my project and it is important to be correct.

Comment: @misty I've tested it. Works perfectly on my production app

Comment: After cloning, when you modify the original object, it is modifying the clone as well.

Comment: I also have the same problem, when I change the properties of the original object then the values are changed in the cloned object.

Comment: This is wrong in that it is *not* a deep copy which was asked for.

Comment: This method clone the pointer which points for the cloneable object, but all the properties inside both objects are the same, So there is a new object created in the memory, but the data inside each object is the same data from memory

Comment: To Bhasker Tiwari's defense however, the example given concerns a `String` reference only, which is perfectly safe (and infact preferred) to share among copies. Admittedly it should have been made clear that this is a special case and that further action needs to be taken when deep cloning objects with references to mutable objects.

Answer (score 47):

Why is there no answer for using Reflection API?

```
private static Object cloneObject(Object obj){
        try{
            Object clone = obj.getClass().newInstance();
            for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(clone, field.get(obj));
            }
            return clone;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It's really simple.

EDIT: Include child object via recursion

```
private static Object cloneObject(Object obj){
        try{
            Object clone = obj.getClass().newInstance();
            for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if(field.get(obj) == null || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())){
                    continue;
                }
                if(field.getType().isPrimitive() || field.getType().equals(String.class)
                        || field.getType().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class)
                        || field.getType().equals(Boolean.class)){
                    field.set(clone, field.get(obj));
                }else{
                    Object childObj = field.get(obj);
                    if(childObj == obj){
                        field.set(clone, clone);
                    }else{
                        field.set(clone, cloneObject(field.get(obj)));
                    }
                }
            }
            return clone;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks much better, but you only need to consider final fields as setAccessible(true) might fail, so maybe u need to separately handle the exception IllegalAccessException thrown when calling field.set(clone, field.get(obj)) separately.

Comment: I liked it so much but can you refactor it to use generics ? 

private static <T> T cloneObject(T obj) { .... }

Comment: I think it's issue when we have reference from properties to it parents: 
`Class A { 
  B child;
}
Class B{
 A parent;
}`

Comment: It fails even int this situation, need to be handled, i will play with it tomorow.   `class car { car car = new car(); }`

Comment: This is not cloning the property with their values. Always returning a cloned object with all properties set to null

Comment: worked for me.  i would change line `field.getType().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class)` to `(field.getType().getSuperclass() != null && field.getType().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class))` to avoid NPE when field type has no superclass

Comment: I had some issues related to null values using getSuperClass, which can be solved using `Number.class.equals(field.getType().getSuperclass())` and with arrays it didn't worked, which can be fixed like this `if(Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())){
                    Object[] values = ((Object[])field.get(obj));
                    Object[] valuesClone = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
                    field.set(clone, valuesClone);
                }`

Comment: This is error prone. Not sure how will it handle collections

Comment: @WillingLearner, this creates a shallow copy, right? And what about fields inherited from super classes? I assume you would want to recurse on `getSuperClass()` to make sure these fields are copied too?

Answer (score 34):

I use Google's JSON library to serialize it then create a new instance of the serialized object. It does deep copy with a few restrictions:

- there can't be any recursive references
- it won't copy arrays of disparate types
- arrays and lists should be typed or it won't find the class to instantiate
- you may need to encapsulate strings in a class you declare yourself

I also use this class to save user preferences, windows and whatnot to be reloaded at runtime. It is very easy to use and effective.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

public class SerialUtils {

//___________________________________________________________________________________

public static String serializeObject(Object o) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String serializedObject = gson.toJson(o);
    return serializedObject;
}
//___________________________________________________________________________________

public static Object unserializeObject(String s, Object o){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object object = gson.fromJson(s, o.getClass());
    return object;
}
       //___________________________________________________________________________________
public static Object cloneObject(Object o){
    String s = serializeObject(o);
    Object object = unserializeObject(s,o);
    return object;
}
}
```

Comment: This works great. But watch out if you try to clone something like List<Integer>. It will be buggy, my Integers got turned into Doubles, 100.0. It took me a long while to understand why are they like that. The solution was to clone Integers them one by one and add to the list in a cycle.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you are just making a reference to the object. You can clone the object if it implements `Cloneable`.

Check out this wiki article about copying objects.

[Refer here: Object copying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Copying_in_Java)

Answer (score 18):

Add `Cloneable` and below code to your class

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
```

Use this  `clonedObject = (YourClass) yourClassObject.clone();`

Answer (score 18):

Deep Cloning is your answer, which requires implementing the `Cloneable` interface and overriding the `clone()` method.

```
public class DummyBean implements Cloneable {

   private String dummy;

   public void setDummy(String dummy) {
      this.dummy = dummy;
   }

   public String getDummy() {
      return dummy;
   }

   @Override
   public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      DummyBean cloned = (DummyBean)super.clone();
      cloned.setDummy(cloned.getDummy());
      // the above is applicable in case of primitive member types like String 
      // however, in case of non primitive types
      // cloned.setNonPrimitiveType(cloned.getNonPrimitiveType().clone());
      return cloned;
   }
}
```

You will call it like this
`DummyBean dumtwo = dum.clone();`

Comment: `dummy`, a `String`, is immutable, you don't need to copy it

Answer (score 13):

This works too. Assuming model

```
class UserAccount{
   public int id;
   public String name;
}
```

First add
`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'` to your app>gradle & sync. Then

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
updateUser = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(mUser),UserAccount.class);
```

You can exclude using a field by using `transient` keyword after access modifier.

**Note:** This is bad practice. Also don't recommend to use `Cloneable` or `JavaSerialization` It's slow and broken. Write copy constructor for best performance [ref](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).

Something like

```
class UserAccount{
        public int id;
        public String name;
        //empty constructor
        public UserAccount(){}
        //parameterize constructor
        public UserAccount(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        //copy constructor
        public UserAccount(UserAccount in){
            this(in.id,in.name);
        }
    }
```

**Test stats of 90000 iteration:**
Line `UserAccount clone = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(aO), UserAccount.class);` takes **808ms**

Line `UserAccount clone = new UserAccount(aO);` takes less than **1ms**

**Conclusion:** Use gson if your boss is crazy and you prefer speed. Use second copy constructor if you prefer quality.

You can also use copy constructor code [generator plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7225-generatecopyconstructor) in Android Studio.

Comment: Why did you suggest it if it's bad practice?

Comment: Thanks @ParthMehrotra now improved

Answer (score 10):

Here's a decent explanation of `clone()` if you end up needing it...

[Here: clone (Java method)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)

Answer (score 10):

Use a deep cloning utility:

```
SomeObjectType copy = new Cloner().deepClone(someObject);
```

This will deep copy any java object, check it out at https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning

Comment: didn't work for me using a custom class. getting the following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory

Answer (score 10):

Alternative to [egaga's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869078/1876355) constructor method of copy. You probably already have a POJO, so just add another method `copy()` which returns a copy of the initialized object.

```
class DummyBean {
    private String dummyStr;
    private int dummyInt;

    public DummyBean(String dummyStr, int dummyInt) {
        this.dummyStr = dummyStr;
        this.dummyInt = dummyInt;
    }

    public DummyBean copy() {
        return new DummyBean(dummyStr, dummyInt);
    }

    //... Getters & Setters
}
```

If you already have a `DummyBean` and want a copy:

```
DummyBean bean1 = new DummyBean("peet", 2);
DummyBean bean2 = bean1.copy(); // <-- Create copy of bean1 

System.out.println("bean1: " + bean1.getDummyStr() + " " + bean1.getDummyInt());
System.out.println("bean2: " + bean2.getDummyStr() + " " + bean2.getDummyInt());

//Change bean1
bean1.setDummyStr("koos");
bean1.setDummyInt(88);

System.out.println("bean1: " + bean1.getDummyStr() + " " + bean1.getDummyInt());
System.out.println("bean2: " + bean2.getDummyStr() + " " + bean2.getDummyInt());
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> bean1: peet 2
> bean2: peet 2
>
> bean1: koos 88
> bean2: peet 2
> ```

But both works well, it is ultimately up to you...

Answer (score 8):

Use `gson` for duplicating an object.

```
public static <T>T copyObject(Object object){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(object).getAsJsonObject();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonObject,(Type) object.getClass());
}
```

Assume I have an object `person`.So

```
Person copyPerson = copyObject(person);
```

**Note:** The performance is much slower.

Comment: Thats a Good idea!

Answer (score 7):

To do that you have to clone the object in some way. Although Java has a cloning mechanism, don't use it if you don't have to. Create a copy method that does the copy work for you, and then do:

```
dumtwo = dum.copy();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475842/copy-an-object-in-java) is some more advice on different techniques for accomplishing a copy.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the object that you want to copy and get the object you want:

```
private Object copyObject(Object objSource) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(objSource);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            bos.close();
            byte[] byteData = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData);
            try {
                objDest = new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objDest;

    }
```

Now parse the `objDest` to desired object.

Happy Coding!

Comment: A good solution to have a solution. But if the purpose of cloning is to improve performance, this solution is not working because it has a heavy processesing

Answer (score 6):

Other than explicitly copying, another approach is to make the object immutable (no `set` or other mutator methods). In this way the question never arises. Immutability becomes more difficult with larger objects, but that other side of that is that it pushes you in the direction of splitting into coherent small objects and composites.

Answer (score 4):

```
class DB {
  private String dummy;

  public DB(DB one) {
    this.dummy = one.dummy; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deep copy automatically with XStream, from http://x-stream.github.io/:

> XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back
>   again.

Add it to your project (if using maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>                
</dependency>
```

Then

```
DummyBean dum = new DummyBean();
dum.setDummy("foo");
DummyBean dumCopy = (DummyBean) XSTREAM.fromXML(XSTREAM.toXML(dum));
```

With this you have a copy without the need to implement any cloning interface.

Comment: Converting to/from XML doesn't seem very ... elegant. To put it mildly!

Comment: Take a look to `java.beans.XMLEncoder` for a standard Java API that serializes to XML too (although not precisely for deep copy purposes).

Comment: do you realize how heavy this is ?

Comment: Way to much overhead in my opinion, since you need to add a 3rd party library and do object serialization which most likely has a huge performance impact.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {

private boolean myField= false;
// and other fields or objects

public MyClass (){}

@Override
public MyClass clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
   try
   {
       MyClass clonedMyClass = (MyClass)super.clone();
       // if you have custom object, then you need create a new one in here
       return clonedMyClass ;
   } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return new MyClass();
   }

  }
}
```

and in your code:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
// do some work with this object
MyClass clonedMyClass = myClass.clone();
```

Comment: There is no point in set "throws CloneNotSupportedException" in the declaration if you try catch the exception and is not thrown up. So, you can just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement `Cloneable` and use the `clone()` method; however, if you use the clone method you should - by standard - ALWAYS override `Object`'s `public Object clone()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add an annotation to the source file, an annotation processor or code generator like [this one](https://github.com/h908714124/zerobuilder) can be used.

```
import net.zerobuilder.BeanBuilder

@BeanBuilder
public class DummyBean { 
  // bean stuff
}
```

A class `DummyBeanBuilders` will be generates, which has a static method `dummyBeanUpdater` to create shallow copies, the same way as you would do it manually.

```
DummyBean bean = new DummyBean();
// Call some setters ...
// Now make a copy
DummyBean copy = DummyBeanBuilders.dummyBeanUpdater(bean).done();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Kotlin extension function

```
fun <T : Any?> T.duplicate(): T? {
    var copyObject: T? = null
    try {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val objectOutputStream = ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this)
        objectOutputStream.flush()
        objectOutputStream.close()
        byteArrayOutputStream.close()
        val byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        val byteArrayInputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(byteData)
        try {
            copyObject = ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream).readObject() as T
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return copyObject
}
```

#### Use case

```
var object = Any()
var duplicateObject = object.duplicate()
```

## Java

```
<T extends Object> T copyObject(T sourceObject) {

    T copyObject = null;

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(sourceObject);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData);
        try {
            copyObject = (T) new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream).readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return copyObject;
}
```

#### Use case

```
Object object = new Object();
Object duplicateObject = copyObject(object);
```

==============================================

## Kotlin Update

If you use data class then you will have copy method that copies the Kotlin data class. Cool thing is you could also pass some values to modify the object with new copy. I would recommend this way.

Example:

//class

```
data class TestModel(val title: String, var subtitle: String)
```

#### Use case

```
val testClass = TestModel("Test title", "Test subtitle")

val newInstance = testClass.copy(subtitle = "new subtitle for copy instance")
```