# Workaround for Hibernate lazy initialisation not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

So I'm making a deep copy of an object using method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2128216/12008421) (serialise and deserialise).

Before doing the clone, I'll need to initialise a List in the object so that the copy can have it. This is what I did:

```java
Product prod = getProdFromDB();
//initialise someList
prod.getSomeList();

Product copiedProd = clone(prod);
// errors out because it's not copied
copiedProd.getSomeList()
```

Although I've added `prod.getSomeList()` before clone, it doesn't do the job for me.
Interesting thing is, if I run `prod.getSomeList()` manually in debugging mode, then copiedProd will have someList in it.
As a stopgap, instead of simply do `prod.getSomeList()`, I need to assign it to a variable and use the variable before clone:

```java
List someList = prod.getSomeList();
System.out.println(someList);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is this? My guess is that Java sees that `getSomeList` isn't doing anything so has it removed from compiled code (something done by JIT?)
2. Apparently `System.out.println(someList)` isn't an elegant way, is there some other ways I can use? (I don't have Hibernate lib in this project so Hibernate::initialise is not an option)

Thanks in advance!

---

FYI this is the clone method:

```java
    private static <T extends Serializable> T clone(T obj) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bout);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bin);
            return (T) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try prod.getSomeList().size() ?

Comment: prod.getSomeList() does not trigger the lazy loading prod.getSomeList().size would trigger it. BUT the question is how do you load the data? You can use JOIN FETCH to load the relationships in the query