# How to implement deep clone of an object

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

Using Java,  how to implement deep clone of an object?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475842/copy-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to implement deep clone is using copy constructor technique.

example in this [link](http://www.xenoveritas.org/blog/xeno/java_copy_constructors_and_clone)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 types of copy :

- shallow copy
- deep copy

shallow copy constructs a new instance of your object, but do not constructs new instance for fields your object might have.
deep copy constructs a new instance of your object, and constructs new instance for fields your object might have, fields of these, etc.

You can have a look on clone() method of ArrayList for more details :
this is a shallow copy. If you want deep copy, you have to clone each element your list contains.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getters and setters.
}

// deep copy:
Person source = new Person("james", 20);
Person dest = new Person();
dest.setName(source.getName());
dest.setAge(source.getAge());
```

Comment: This will work as age has a primitive type and name has an immutable type, but won't work with higher level object

Comment: yeah, this **deep copy** need to be done recursively if there are another object in **Person**.